# $XX^t=A$, $X=?$. Where $X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diophantine-equations

**The problem:**

$XX^t=A$,
$\quad$ ($X_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$, $\quad$ $\sum_{j=1}^m x_{ij}=2$),
 $\quad$ $X=?$

**Details:**

$n,m \in N$

$A \in \{0,1,2\}^{n \times n}$

$X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times m}$

$A$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix where the diagonal is always 2 and having off-diagonal elements just $1$ or $0$.

> $(i \neq j)$ -> $A_{ij}=A_{ji}\in\{0,1\}$
>
> $A_{ii}=2$

For example:

$$A=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Also, $X$ is a $n \times m$ matrix where its entries are either $1$ or $0$ i.e. $X_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ and columns have sum equal $2$:

> $X_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$
>   $$\sum_{j=1}^m x_{ij}=2$$

For example:

$$X=X^T=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

And now, $$
XX^T=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So,

> $XX^t=A$

How can to find all $X$ matrices who satisfies this equation?

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74143/matrices-xx-top-a-x/74161#74161) a bit general problem.

I would like a human readable process (to understand the process) and a way how to use Matlab, Mathematica or gap to solve this without brute force algorithms (just clever math).

Looking the answer of the another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74143/matrices-xx-top-a-x/74161#74161). I had found recently these links.

[Completly Positive Matrices](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=BFXSPAUB)

[Solving X times Transpose of X Is Equal to A - Over Integers](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=Q4NLC7AT)

[Representation of Groups - An Computational Approach](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=KP17EG6K) See 2.8.15 on page 161.

Comment: Do you really mean $a_{ii}=0$? The diagonal of $XX^t$ is the dot product of the $i^{th}$-row of $X$ with itself. This is the length of the $i^{th}$-row squared so if it's zero then the entire row is zero and so $X=0$. Your assumption $\sum_{j} x_{ij}=2$ forces the diagonal of $A$ to be 2's.

Comment: Yes but, if the diagonal of A is irrelevant to me, can be 0 or 2 or 3 or any other number...I just need the equation holds to the other values of ${a_i}_j$.

Comment: Is your constraint that $\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij}=2$ for the $3\times3$ case, or in general?

Comment: Note that if $B$ is orthogonal (so $BB^t=I$), then $(XB)(XB)^t=XX^t$, so if your equation has one solution, it has lots and lots of them.

Comment: @Mike Wierzbicki, it's for a $nxn$ matrix.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, very interesting, dont thought that. Thx. Unfortunally find solutions is the problem...But I will remember you process, really helpull.

Comment: I think it's a really good question to ask. I not intermediate in Linear Algebra so, this recently founded articles above maybe can't help me so much, but I will try to read them all soon. Appreciate if anyone have a easier solution. Thx.

Comment: *Hint on why there is a limited response to this question:* This is an [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem. Actually a variant of TSP.

Comment: The change from "its" to "it's" in your last edit was wrong; the contraction of "it is" is spelled with an apostrophe and the possessive pronoun for "it" is spelled without one.

Comment: Observation (that you've probably made already):  for any such $X$, each row has to have exactly two 1's.  For a given $n$, that gives only ${n \choose 2}$ possible candidates (which is probably better than $mn$).

Comment: Yes @JackManey. That's true. But unfortunally probably we need implement a brute force algorithm. And I would like another way. Edited the question evidenciate this. Thx about the contribution.